# Fixing an overfull box

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, hyphenation, warnings, microtype

I have an overfull box in a French text which looks like this:

[image: overfull box]

The sequence at the end of the line is:

```
d'Ananias~: \og Vous
```

"Vous" cannot be hyphenated and `\og` inserts a non-secable space, so the only place where it could be cut is after the colon.

I'm using XeTeX with microtype (2.5 beta6 for XeTeX support). How can I fix this overfull box?

Do I have to allow lines to stretch more (and how)?

Comment: I think that the best and easiest thing to do is recomposing the phrase before the colon!

Comment: @Spike: I'm afraid that is not an option.

Comment: @Raphink: I don't use XeTeX, but with pdfTeX, passing the `draft` document class option to the `microtype` package will disable all micro-typographic extensions. Solution: Load `microtype` with the `final` option -- this may influence line-breaks.

Comment: @lockstep: I haven't passed the `draft` option. Instead, I use `\overfullrule=1mm` in the preamble, so only overfull boxes are debugged without affecting the rest.

Comment: Try to add `\emergencystretch=1.5em` in the preamble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link [Overfull](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-overfull) gives  "More satisfactory is to make small changes to `\tolerance`, incrementally, and then to look to see how the change affects the result; very small increases can often do what’s necessary."

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[draft,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[textwidth=13cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[protrusion = true,
            final]{microtype}    

\begin{document}

%\tolerance=270
  Voici l'accusation que Pierre a formulée à l'encontre d'Ananias: \og Vous avez menti à l'Esprit-Saint. \fg{} Il est également possible de blasphémer contre le Ciel, contre les saints, contre la vertu.

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\tolerance=270`
[image]

I think `expansion` does not work with `xelatex`

Comment: The result is indeed nicer this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Try to add `\emergencystretch=1.5em` in the preamble. This way, TeX's line-breaking algorithm will try a third time with the value of `\emergencystretch` added to the allowed space between words per line. (`1.5em` is half the value of `\sloppy` which should only be used as a last resort.)

Comment: This (on top of `microtype`) actually fixes 3/4 of my overfull lines. Thanks!