# Black rectangle at end of line - how to get rid of

Tags: symbols

What does the black rectangle at the end of the line mean? It is overflow?

[image]

This writes overflow

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage

\begin{document}

\begin{description}

\item [Epocha (ekvinokcium)]
$T$ udává okamžik v čase. Je několik druhů epoch - referenční epocha (v případě světelných křivek udává, kdy je fáze 0), epocha maximální radiální rychlosti, epocha periastra, epocha primárního minima, apod. Udává se v různých časových jednotkách: 

\begin{itemize}
\item Juliánská data se hodí na analýzu dlouhých časových pozorování. Označují střední sluneční dny, které začínají v poledne světového času SČ, což je lokální čas na poledníku procházejícím observatoří v Greenwichi. Počátek těchto časových jednotek JD0 připadá na střední poledne v Greenwichi 1. ledna 4713 př. n. l.  

\end{itemize}

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually it indicates an overfull box, but you have to enable this manually.

Comment: In `draft` mode (or with other 'debug'-like settings) those boxes indicate overfull boxes, which means in that case that the line protrudes into the margin because LaTeX can't find a good point to break it.

Comment: I tried this `\overfullrule=1mm` and nothing happend. When I add `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{report}` pictures and links don't work.

Comment: Do you want to enable or disable the black box? I.e. do you have a box at the moment and do you want to get rid of it or have it?

Comment: @Elisabeth - Enabling the `draft` option definitely affects the way the `graphicx` and `hyperref` packages do their job. (Do you maybe not know what the word "draft" means in a document context?) Incidentally, the expression "nothing happened" is not helpful. Are you maybe saying that the document didn't compile at all? If that is *not* what you're saying, do try to provide a more meaningful description of (a) what you're trying to achieve and (b) what you're actually doing.

Comment: I would like to disable (I did a mistake in meaning of this word before) the black box. I don't know what draft mean. Maybe a concept? "Nothing happend" I ment that the black box didn't disappear, however, the compilation was sucessful. So I want to get rid of the black boxes.

Comment: There are several possible ways to *enable* this behaviour as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75140/ shows. That means that there are several possible ways to disable the box when it appears, but which method is successful depends on the way the box was enabled in the first place. If you can't find a `draft` setting anywhere, either something sets `draft` implicitly or the box was enabled with a different setting. We can only help you properly if you show us a short example document that reproduces the behaviour you are seeing (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: @Mico Since the OP confirmed above that she wants to *disable* the black box and not enable it would you remove the duplicate suggestion, please?

Comment: There must be *something* in your document that causes this behaviour. Take a **copy** of your large document and delete as much stuff as you can while still retaining the black box. That way it should be possible to create a minimal working example. Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl and http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html for more help on creating MWEs.

Comment: I found it: Overfull \hbox (0.89655pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 84--84

Comment: Well yes, the table is slightly too wide for the page. But note that your code does *not* produce black rectangles for overfull boxes, so if you get black rectangles in your real document they must come from code not shown above.

Comment: @moewe - Note that the newly-supplied code doesn't generate any black rectangles (aka "slugs"). It's not even the case that the `tabularx` material is wider than the textblock. Instead, it is one word, in one cell, that's too wide for that cell. I already informed the OP in a comment below an earlier posting how to create a fix: simply change `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` to `\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}`. I guess my suggestion wasn't taken seriously.

Comment: @moewe - I've withdrawn the duplicate-posting note, per your request. Note that the warning the OP is encountering in his/her code has nothing to do with overfull-line slugs, as one might be tempted to assume is the case on the basis of the posting's title.

Comment: I forgot it, I am sorry. So the table has no black box. There is one in description and itemize list. I added code to my question. The are waring in the MWE and one word is out. There is a black box in main document like on the picture. Thank you

Comment: @Elisabeth - Your updated code still doesn't produce a black rectangle anywhere.

Comment: I know, it is only in main code. But have you got a warning about overflow in this code? I have. I think that it is needy to solve.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. Apparently we were too late though, the question did get closed in the end.

Comment: @Elisabeth The example indeed produces an overfull box for me, but that is caused by the minimality of the example: For good line breaking of non-English (Czech? Slovak?) texts, you should load `babel` with the correct language option. If you use pdfLaTeX you should also load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to allow line-breaking of words with accented characters.

Comment: @moewe - When the query was first posted, it was ostensibly about the meaning of slugs (little black rectangles at the end of overfull lines). No question was asked about how to get rid of the slugs. That's when I nominated the question for closure as a duplicate. The LaTeX code shown in the query has changed several times since then, and the question posed implicitly by the code (though not the question's title) has changed considerably with each iteration. At present, the LaTeX code and the title of the query have virtually nothing in common.

Comment: @Mico Yes, the question has change a lot over time. I would agree that the first version was (at face value) about the *meaning* of the rectangles. (It was not about how to enable them, which I think would be a different question.) After a short exchange in the comments, the OP asked in the comments how to *enable* this behaviour. Naturally then the suggested duplicate appeared reasonable to people. There was, however, a misunderstanding: The OP actually wants to get rid of the slugs (*dis*able them), hence my request to withdraw the duplicate suggestion. ...

Comment: ... I personally think that for quick duplicate votes (i.e. only a few hours after the question was posted, especially if the OP is still engaging in responding to comments) one should wait for explicit feedback by the OP that the duplicate does indeed solve the issue.

Comment: I used `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` and I had before `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. There is still overflow. What an abbreviation OP means?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/35864. Concrete help is always a bit tricky. I can still reproduce an overfull box in your example if I add `fontenc` and `babel` (though it is far better than before): `microtype` might help, sometimes it is also recommended to just rewrite/reformulate the offending sentence so it breaks nicer (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20585/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209229/35864)

Comment: Thank you very much `\hfuzz=99pt` helped

Comment: Note that according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50830/35864 `\hfuzz` only affects the warnings and not the actual typesetting. That means that the line still protrudes into the margin and will look unsightly, but you have told TeX to not warn you about it. That seems to be the worst workaround.

Comment: It doesn't look so bad   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb0LI.png

Comment: Sure, the box was only overfull by a very small amount. So it was hardly noticeable in the first place. Still you have only turned off the warning, you did not actually resolve the underlying issue of the overfull box.